# Security Rules: Storing unique usernames in one document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

On my app I am trying to make it so that users have to have a unique username.

My current method is to have a `Social` Collection with one document called `Usernames`. That document will store the users `userID` as the key for the field and then their `username` for the value.

I am struggling to write the correct security rules for this. I would like it so that:

- All signed-in users can get this document
- Users can only update their own data in the document, formatted as [theirUserId: theirUsername]
- There can be no duplicate usernames, e.g.

  - userIdA: "foo"
  - userIdB: "foo"

At the moment the only point that I can't get to work is checking to see whether a username is already taken.

Another solution I have thought of is to reverse the fields (username: userID). But I can't figure out a way how to write the security rules for this method either.

**Current Rules**

```
// Usernames

match /Social/Usernames {
    allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;
    allow update: if isUserNameAvailable();
}

// Functions

function isUserNameAvailable() {
    // This line works
    return (request.writeFields.hasOnly([request.auth.uid]))

    // This one doesn't
        && !(resource.data.values().hasAny([request.writeFields[request.auth.uid]]));
}
```

**Firestore Data Structure**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: `request.writeFields` is problematic and deprecated and should not be used.  It will stop working in the future. Bear in mind also that documents can be no more than 1MB in size total, so if you try to store information about all your users in a single document, this will not scale.

Comment: Would you recommend storing each user's `username` in a separate document as a better solution? My only concern is that this method will massively increase the read count on search results? Many thanks.

Comment: That would be the only way to properly scale this.